# scheme sort list diffent criteria

Tags: scheme

I have a finite list of quadruples, e.g.

```
(list (list 1 3 5 5) (list 2 3 4 9) (list 3 4 4 6)(list 4 7 10 3)).
```

I denote each of the elements by (a1 a2 a3 a4).

Please help me to write a sorting function which provides 
a "increasing" list created according to the following criteria:

1. the numbers a2,
2. later the difference (a3 - a4),
3. and later the numbers a3.

Please help if you can.

Comment: Just so you know, people appreciate when you show that you've made an effort to accomplish your goal. If you don't share what you have tried and where you got stuck, it might look like you're asking people to do it all for you.

Comment: I am working on a bigger program. I can not paste it here, it is too big.
The question I have is the last step. Thank you for your help. Debbbie.

Comment: The criteria denote what to sort by? So, for quadruples whose numbers a2 match, you then compare their (a3 - a4)s?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, your ordered criteria are the order in which to sort. If this is the case, then the following program should perform that sorting.

```
(define (strange-sort quadruples)
  (define (a2 quad)
    (cadr quad))
  (define (a3 quad)
    (caddr quad))
  (define (a4 quad)
    (cadddr quad))
  (sort quadruples
        (lambda (x y)
          (cond ((< (a2 x) (a2 y))
                 #t)
                ((> (a2 x) (a2 y))
                 #f)
                (else
                 (cond ((< (- (a3 x) (a4 x))
                           (- (a3 y) (a4 y)))
                        #t)
                       ((> (- (a3 x) (a4 x))
                           (- (a3 y) (a4 y)))
                        #f)
                       (else
                        (cond ((< (a3 x) (a3 y))
                               #t)
                              (else #f)))))))))
```

Comment: Dear Arafinwe, 

Thank you so much for your help and a code. Now I see the point, so I can add 
additional criteria to sort quadruples. However, please modify it slightly in the line 
"sort quadruples" to make it working. Wishes, Debbie.

Comment: @DebbieMigórska Hmm. Does your implementation not have a `sort` function? Can you tell me what implementation of Scheme you're using? This program works fine for me (on MIT/GNU Scheme).