# Scheme quadruples sorting different criteria

Tags: sorting, scheme, criteria

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [scheme sort list diffent criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649013/scheme-sort-list-diffent-criteria)

I have a finite list of quadruples, like

```
(list (list 1 3 5 5) (list 2 3 4 9) (list 3 4 4 6)(list 4 7 10 3)).
```

Each of the elements is denoted by (a1 a2 a3 a4).
I have wrote a code which provides the above list and I have stopped
since I have no idea how to continue. I want to write a sorting function
which provides a "increasing" list created according to the following 
criteria:

1. the numbers a2,
2. later the difference (a3 - a4),
3. and later the numbers a3.

I kindly ask for your help. Thank you. Debbie.
I can not include my code since it is not accepted in this place.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a predicate that seems to do what you want. You can plug it into this [`mergesort`](http://en.literateprograms.org/Merge_sort_%28Scheme%29) to work.

```
(define <quad
  (lambda (l1 l2)
    (let
      ([l1a2 (cadr l1)]
       [l1a3 (caddr l1)]
       [l1a3 (cadddr l1)]
       [l2a2 (cadr l2)]
       [l2a3 (caddr l2)]
       [l2a3 (cadddr l2)])
      (cond
        [(< l1a2 l2a2) #t]
        [(< (- l1a3 l1a4) (- l2a3 l2a4)) #t]
        [(< l1a3 l2a3) #t]))))
```

If you pass that in for the predicate argument, your sort should work fine:

```
(merge-sort <quad '((2 3 4 5) (1 2 3 4))) => ((1 2 3 4) (2 3 4 5))
```